# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute called 'find_all'

Tags: python

I am currently making a webscraper to scrape https://ncov2019.live/data/world and im having trouble trying to scrape the table header. When I do

```
head = soup.find('table',{"class" : "display responsive dataTable no-footer"}).find_all("tr")

table_header = head.find_all('th')
```

it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\ncov2019live.py", line 13, in <module>
head = soup.find('table',{"class" : "display responsive dataTable no-footer"}).find_all("tr")[1:]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Evidently `soup.find` returned None, which presumably means that the thing you were asking it to find was not found.

Comment: review the source - that class doesn't match the tables I see

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the website is client render. So you need to wait the website rendering all data.

That is why `soup.find` return `None` object.

Answer (score 0):

The class your're looking from is probably generated at client side and it is not available through bs.

If you inspect the soup in debug you'll see that some useful IDs are available, and you can use those to get the informations needed (see code below)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# get the BS object
url = "https://ncov2019.live/data/world"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

# if you look at all 'table's tag in debug you'll see all the available IDs
head = soup.find_all('table')  # <--- not needed really. It's just for test
```

here we get the table with the column names. Also theres only one table with this ID with only a row, so use `find()` instead of `find_all()`

```
head_th = soup.find(id='sortable_table_saved').find('tr')

# prints the field names
print('NAMES')
for th in head_th.find_all('th'):
    print(th.string)
```

here we get the table with the values. Here `find_all()` is necessary

```
items = soup.find(id='sortable_table_world').find_all('tr')
print('ITEMS')

for tr in items:
    print(tr)
```

Gook luck with your scraping !